# Ajax call is not working in visual studio code(June 2020)

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, visual-studio-code

I am trying to fetch data from openWeather API.It is working in sublime text but not in visual studio code(2020).Below is my code:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
$("#submitweather").click(function() {
    if ($("#city").val() != null) {
        $.ajax({
            url: "https://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=" + $("#city").val() + "&units=metric&appid=" + "16730653e7fb54b543203fcee48a7abb",
            type: "GET",
            dataType: "json",
            async: true,
            success: function(result) {

                console.log(result);
            },
            error: function(err) {

                console.log(err);
            }

        });
    } else
        alert("city name should be entered");
});
  });
```

HTML Code :

```
<div class="col-md-12">

            <form>
                <div class="row pb-5">
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <input type=" text" id="city" placeholder="Enter city" class="form-control">
                    </div>
                    <div class="col-md-6">
                        <button id="submitweather"  class="btn btn-warning px-5">Search</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
```

Comment: Can you add in the error as well, which you are encountering. Thanks.

Comment: Don't post API keys in public forums like this. BTW, This code is working fine for me

Answer (score 0):

Not knowing the specific error, I've had JS issues similar to this between editors because of hidden control characters after some copy and pasting. Make sure you don't have any hidden escape/control characters in your code.

Comment: @yashiagrawal what doesn't work? does it hit your error handler, or does it just not come back at all? or do you get a different error when running the code?